# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on string - connecting to SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server, sqlsrv

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\database.php:75 Stack trace: #0
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\rankings.php(17):
> database::query('SELECT TOP 10 *...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\app.php(65): rankings->index() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\engine.php(97): App->__construct() #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(4): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\database.php on line 75

I'm having issues with this error. I'm trying to connect my VPS running Xammpp to another VPS that is running SQL Server. I've opened port 1433 on the SQL Server VPS, and I'm trying to connect with this code right now, all the credentials are correct but it's returning this error. I've also already installed the Microsoft SQL Server drivers for PHP and enabled them on Xampp as well as checked PHPInfo to confirm this.

```
public static function conexao()
{
        global $con;

        try
        {
            $db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=XXXXX;Database=XX",'XX','XXXX');

            $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
}
```

Comment: Where the code that calls the `query()` method? According to the error message you're trying to call `query()` on a string object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.